# KL-divergence between degenerate and non-degenerate distribution?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta, entropy

Can I compute the KL-divergence between, e.g. the Uniform distribution on $\{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2 | y=0 \}$ (q) and the Uniform distribution on $[0,1]^2$ (p). It seems to me like I should be able to, since I only need to integrate over the area where q is defined.  Is there any justification for this (maybe with some generalized notion of the KL)?

Here is my attempt to work out the math in this case:

$q = U(\{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2 | x = y \}) \implies q(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \delta(x-y)$

$p = U([0,1]^2) \implies p(x,y) = 1$

$KL(q || p) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 q(x,y) \log\frac{q(x,y)}{p(x,y)} dx dy$

At this point, we get a delta function inside the log, which according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833544/does-the-derivative-of-the-log-of-the-delta-function-exist), is undefined.

FYI, The example I'm actually interested in is:
$$KL(q(\mathbf{z}) || p(\mathbf{z}))$$ where $p(\mathbf{z}) = \mathcal{N}(0, I)$ and $\mathbf{z} = g\mathbf{v}$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is a constant and $g$ is drawn from some known distribution ($g \sim q_g(g)$).

Comment: What does $g\sim q_g(g)$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the KL divergence for probability measures like this (which are mutually singular) is defined to be infinite.  The KL divergence between two measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ is typically defined as

$$
D_{KL}(\mu\|\nu) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\Bbb{E}_\mu\left[\ln\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\right] & \mu\ll \nu \\
\infty & \text{else}
\end{array}\right. 
$$   This makes sense in your case - if you think about the "information gain" when going from a random quantity that can take any position in $[0,1]^2$ to a random quantity that can only live on the x-axis, you've gained "infinite" information because you've eliminated all uncertainty in the $y$ variable.

If you don't want to think about measures, you can think about approximating your $q$ with a narrow box i.e. let $q(x,y)$ be supported on $[0,1]\times [0,\epsilon]$.  Then compute $D_{KL}$ and let $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Do you think it would make any sense to generalize the KL to just be the integral over q(z) of the ratio of q(z) / p(z), ignoring the delta function?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You can define many things, whether or not they are meaningful is another matter.  As long as you're precise and show that your definition is well defined and meaningful, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @icurays1 - when you say "usually", can you reference any text or source for this?

Comment: @Carl I'm pretty sure this definition is in Information Theory by Cover and Thomas